# Selenium-webdriver script breaks loop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, while-loop

I had been tasked with fixing a digital sign loop running off python in the office. The original script was lost due to a OS crash and I had to recreate it. I am at my python limits on fixing what I had been able to create using selenium.

I wrote the below script and it functions for random periods of time before the loop breaks and the script must be executed again.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

website = ["https://www.fireeye.com/cyber-map/threat-map.html",
"https://horizon.netscout.com/?sidebar=close",
"https://www.accuweather.com/en/us/minneapolis/55415/hourly- 
weather-forecast/348794?=page",
"https://www.accuweather.com/en/us/minneapolis/55415/daily- 
weather-forecast/348794?=page"
]

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'/usr/bin/chromedriver') 
driver.get(website[0])
driver.maximize_window()

driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', 'secondtab');")
driver.switch_to.window("secondtab")
driver.get(website[1])

driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', 'thirdtab');")
driver.switch_to.window("thirdtab")
driver.get(website[2])
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,250);")

driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', 'fourthtab');")
driver.switch_to.window("fourthtab")
driver.get(website[3])
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,100);")
```

Can anyone tell me why the loop breaks?

The loop is a while true condition :

```
while True:

    if "FireEye" in driver.title:
        time.sleep(20)
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        
    elif "Attack" in driver.title:
        time.sleep(20)
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
    
    elif "Hourly" in driver.title:
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[3])
        
    elif "Daily" in driver.title:
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

The conditions are checking for the web tab titles of each site and as each should always be true.

It at a random intervals returns the following traceback error:

*driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[3])

IndexError: list index out of range*

I cannot determine what is causing the index to no longer function.

Comment: The obvious answer would be that there are fewer than four windows open, so `window_handles[3]` does not exist.

Comment: Yes, but there are four windows open. The loop functions until it suddenly doesn't. It sometimes runs all day, sometimes breaks within an hour. What could cause it to no longer identify the fourth window?

Comment: Are you _absolutely_ sure that four windows are open?  How are they opened exactly?

Comment: The script auto runs the browser to open chromium, call the website, open a new tab, call the next website. I can see all four tabs open and running in the browser. I haven't crossed any documentation for another method of switching the tabs.

Comment: At the moment the error happens, are there still four windows open?

Comment: Yes, all four window tabs are still open when the index call fails. If a tab is closed while the script is running it while simply cancel without returning the traceback.

Comment: In that case, I have no idea.  I haven't worked much with selenium, and not at all with long-lived selenium applications.  At the top of the loop, try adding some code that checks the length of `driver.window_handles`, and if it's less than 4, then print out a bunch of information (window title, url, etc) about each remaining window.  Maybe that will at least tell you _which_ tab it thinks is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom of this, python thinks there isn't a fourth window open.  So first, let's put in some error handling, something like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        if "FireEye" in driver.title:
            time.sleep(20)
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        
        elif "Attack" in driver.title:
            time.sleep(20)
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
    
        elif "Hourly" in driver.title:
            time.sleep(10)
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[3])
        
        elif "Daily" in driver.title:
            time.sleep(10)
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    except:
        foreach w in driver.window_handles:
            print("{} is open!".format(w))
```

This will at least continue the loop regardless of the error, and tell you what tabs it thinks are open.

Edit: Also, as a note, window_handles is not ordered.  So what may be window_handles[1] in one iteration may end up as window_handles[3] in the next.